# EF Core Scaffolding missing [Required] for Certain Types

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

VS 2019 trying to EF Core scaffolding tables from SQL Server 2012 (v11.07), notice it cannot generate `[Required]` annotation for certain column types: `datetime, datetime2, int`, for example

```
create table dbo.test2 
(
    d datetime not null, 
    d2 datetime2 not null,
    i int not null, 
    txt varchar(100) not null 
)
Scaffold-DbContext "..." 
    -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
    -ContextDir Data -OutputDir "Data/Models" 
    -DataAnnotations -UseDatabaseNames -Tables "test2"
```

Result:

```
{
    [Keyless]
    [Table("test2", Schema = "dbo")]
    public partial class test2
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime d { get; set; }
        public DateTime d2 { get; set; }
        public int i { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string txt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Some project properties:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.10">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `int` and `DateTime` properties are not marked as nullable (with `?` sign - e.g. `int?`) - they are considered as `Required` by default. It is applied only to value types (structs as `DateTime` or primitives as `int`). You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt)